# Can I pipe a webpage's source from curl to perl?

Tags: perl, curl

I'm parsing the sourcecode of many websites, an entire huge web with thousands of pages. Now I want to search for stuff in perĺ, I want to find the number of occurrences of a keyword.

For parsing the webpages I use curl and pipe the output to "grep -c" which doesn't work, so I want to use perl. Can be perl utilised completely to crawl a page?

E.g.

```
cat RawJSpiderOutput.txt | grep parsed | awk -F " " '{print $2}' | xargs -I replaceStr curl replaceStr?myPara=en | perl -lne '$c++while/myKeywordToSearchFor/g;END{print$c}'
```

Explanation: In the textfile above I have usable and unusable URLs. With "Grep parsed" I fetch the usable URLs. With awk I select the 2nd column with contains the pure usable URL. So far so good. Now to this question: With Curl I fetch the source (appending some parameter, too) and pipe the whole source code of each page to perl in order to count "myKeywordToSearchFor" occurrences. I would love to do this in perl only if it is possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses Perl only (untested):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Fetch;

my $count;
open my $SPIDER, '<', 'RawJSpiderOutput.txt' or die $!;
while (<$SPIDER>) {
    chomp;
    if (/parsed/) {
        my $url = (split)[1];
        $url .= '?myPara=en';
        my $ff = File::Fetch->new(uri => $url);
        $ff->fetch or die $ff->error;
        my $fetched = $ff->output_file;
        open my $FETCHED, '<', $fetched or die $!;
        while (<$FETCHED>) {
            $count++ if /myKeyword/;
        }
        unlink $fetched;
    }
}
print "$count\n";
```

Comment: This is almost as short as the original shell script :-)  I would have suggested a few things. a) LWP is a bit more standard for fetching, and does not result in a temp file that you have to unlink.  (If you're expecting 10MB+ in data, this may be a point in File::Fetch's favour.) b) this whole thing likely could be sped up with Coro/AnyEvent::HTTP (among other options - these are my favourites right now).  Put URLs into a queue, create a bunch of worker threads, grab an item from the queue and fetch it, scan for keywords.  Make better use of your bandwidth.

Comment: @Tanktalus: The only reason I used File::Fetch here is it is a core module.

Comment: @choroba You probably meant `unlink $fetched`. You also most likely want to split on `' '`, i.e. `(split)[1]`, which will strip excess whitespace, rather than turn them into empty elements in the array.

Comment: `LWP::Simple` is part of the core since Perl v5.12.3

Comment: Zaid: LWP::Simple is not a part of Perl core (in any version). Try running `corelist LWP::Simple`.

Comment: @davorg : You're right that `corelist LWP::Simple` says it's not there, but `perl -MLWP::Simple -e ''` runs just fine on systems where no additional CPAN modules have been installed (at least for v5.12.3). Is this a case of `(or so I think)` or is there a distinction between what's part of the core and what Perl comes bundled with by default?

Comment: @Zaid, IIRC strawberry comes with additional modules, are you using it by chance? Another note: [`HTTP::Tiny`](http://p3rl.org/HTTP::Tiny) is much lighter than LWP. You might also look at [`Mojolicious`](http://mojolicio.us) which has its own UserAgent.

Comment: @Joel : I've seen this on a Mac OS X with v5.12.3.

Comment: @TLP: both true, fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like,

```
   perl -e 'while(<>){my @words = split ' ';for my $word(@words){if(/myKeyword/){++$c}}} print "$c\n"'
```

i.e.

```
   while (<>)               # as long as we're getting input (into “$_”)
   { my @words = split ' '; # split $_ (implicit) into whitespace, so we examine each word
     for my $word (@words)  #  (and don't miss two keywords on one line)
     { if (/myKeyword/)     # whenever it's found,
       { ++$c } } }         # increment the counter (auto-vivified)
   print "$c\n"             # and after end of file is reached, print the counter
```

or, spelled out `strict`-like

```
   use strict;
   my $count = 0;
   while (my $line = <STDIN>) # except that <> is actually more magical than this
   { my @words = split ' ' => $line;
     for my $word (@words)
     { ++$count; } } }
   print "$count\n";
```

Comment: Or, the same code using perl's command-line options: `perl -lane '$c += grep /myKeyword/, @F; END { print $c }'`